# how can i use hibernate to insert into multiple non related tables in parallel?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i have multiple tables like table1 , table 2, table 3 .. all these tables are not related. As of now i am inserting the data sequentially into these tables but i want to increase the insertion speed by doing this in parallel using hibernate.

please help me if there is a way to do it

Comment: Please share your observations and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I mean things work fine with sequential insert but i want to make process little faster if there is any way to do it.

the data that i write to these tables is completely independant i mean non related data.

Comment: Without knowing how you are doing, its hard to suggest you anything. There are numerous way to persist the data into multiple tables parallely but only if you share your existing problems we could help.